# Can Rails use a session store without putting anything on the client, no session_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, redis-server

I'm trying to build an app with no javascript or client session. I've used Redis and find it to work well. I would simply rather not put any session_id on the client. Can this be done?

Found links to the types at [ActiveSupport::Cache](https://msp-greg.github.io/rails_gem_5/ActiveSupport/Cache.html)

```
 # Rails 6.0.3.2
 # config/development.rb
 config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
 config.action_controller.enable_fragment_cache_logging = true
 config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { driver: :hiredis, url: 'redis:127.0.0.1:6379/0' }
 config.session_store :redis_store # or :cache_store, :redis_cashe_store ?

         # ActionDispatch::Session::RedisStore
         # ActionDispatch::Cache::RedisCacheStore
```

Comment: Without any session identifier on the client how are you going to keep track of what session belongs to which client?

Comment: I do not know. Is there a way? Just by getting the client info?

Comment: Its a rhetorical question. There are no truly reliable identifiers. Things like client ip addresses are notoriously flaky. That's why a set of passed state (such as cookies) is used to uniquely identify sessions.